# ruby 2 rails 4 installation using rbenv 2013 in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I go through a lot of tutorials for installation of ruby 2 , rails 4 using rbenv , and all are posted a year ago which lack updates . can anybody help me how to clean installation of ruby , rails using rbenv in ubuntu 12.10 . Any application for this , ? or can i use ruby mate in ubuntu ?

Comment: You have a very strange habit with punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Start with installing rbenv, and then ruby-build to be able to install versions of ruby.  Using the most current versions of rbenv and ruby-build will be all that is necessary.

Then, ask rbenv which versions of Ruby are available, and install a recent one.

Finally, gem install rails will install the most current version of rails.

As long as each step is successful, using a slightly older tutorial should not be a problem.  Don't forget to

```
rbenv rehash
```

at each step to make sure you are using the rbenv shims.